# How to group all review texts of each item together with python-pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Given such an data frame:

```
item_id           review_text 
B0006SIBUC        i was attracted to this 
B0009VEM4U        great snippers
...
B0006SIBUC        i am enjoying using these
```

I'd like to combine all the review texts of each items. So the resulting data frame should be:

```
item_id           review_text
B0006SIBUC        i was attracted to this i am enjoying using these
B0009VEM4U        great snippers
...
```

How can I do that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`groupby/agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#group-by-split-apply-combine), and [`' '.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join the strings in each group into one:

---

For example,

```
In [19]: df = pd.DataFrame({'item_id':['a', 'b', 'a'], 'foo':['X','Y','Z']})

In [20]: df.groupby('item_id').agg(' '.join).reset_index()
Out[20]: 
  item_id  foo
0       a  X Z
1       b    Y
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the resulting data frame of your solution has only one columns? How can I change it to 2 columns as the original data frame be.

Comment: Call `reset_index()`.